Is there a counterpart to "a group acting on a space" to "a ring acting on a space", especially if the space is a (Lie) algebra?
I have read something that comes close to this is a module, but as I have understood, a module requires my space to be an abelian group, which would not be the case for a Lie algebra.
So, if I have got a Lie algebra or any algebra actually, $\mathfrak{g}$, a group $G$ acting on this $G \curvearrowright \mathfrak{g}$ is clearly defined and there are tons of books about this.
Is there something similar for rings? If $R$ was a ring, $R \curvearrowright \mathfrak{g}$?

Group action on a $k-$vector space extends canonically to the action of  the group ring over $k$.

"pendant"?! ${}{}{}$

@Zerox in what way?

@rschwieb ahm yes?

A homomorphism $R\to U\mathfrak g$?

@relativeentropy Sorry the "?!" was meant to convey puzzlement at what this could mean. The body of the post did not provide any further clues. If "pendant" is a term, could you mention it in the body with a link so other readers with my problem can learn about it?

@rschwieb oh wow, you are right, this was a language thing. The english "pendant" means something completely different. What I meant was "counterpart". So sorry, I really did not know that this word means something so different in english.

@relativeentropy I thought it might be it: in the oxford online dictionary, the last entry for pendant is an artistic, literary, or musical composition intended to match or complement another. which is close to that. But OTOH I thought it might have an algebraic definition, since "ring" and "pendant" are types of jewelry...  Thanks for clarifying!

This question is surely relevant: https://mathoverflow.net/q/100565/8103
